# Is there an easy way to select x value of an element in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have a grid which consists of 10X10 squares each with value of x and y.
I want to know how to get the x value of any given square that's clicked.
I already have a function that makes them clickable but inside it I want to add an if statement which includes the x value of square clicked.

I am trying to do something like this:

```
$(this).attr("x");
```

or

```
$(this).attr("xvalue");
```

What would be the correct way to do this?

Comment: Where is the "x" value stored? In an attribute? In the text? Please show us the HTML.

Answer (score 1):

You could store the x and y values in data attributes. Each square would look something like this:

```
<div data-x=9 data-y=5>
Contents
</div>
```

You could then get the x and y values after the click event by:

```
const x = $(this).data('x');
const y = $(this).data('y');
```